# Is it possible to save an html page that still uses jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: browser

Is there a way to save an html file that still contains the user interactions of jQuery and JavaScript?

Comment: How does this has to do anything with html or css? It sounds more like a browser training issue, isn't it? BTW the answer is it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript and CSS are client-side (meaning they run in the browser), yes, you can save the page and use it off-line.

If the JavaScript and CSS are embedded within the HTML then you can have it work as an all-in-one page.

If you right-click on a page and "view source" you can easily download the code.

Note that any server-side interaction (such as PHP, Java, etc) will not work this way.